# CSS: How to remove weird lines

Tags: html, css

I have a button [image: Here]. When I click on it, some weird dotted lines show up like this [image: Wierd dotted lines]which I cannot remove. Tried everything I know in CSS but cannot fix. Please Help.

Here is my css:

```
input.filterIcon {
width: 32px !important;
height: 32px !important;
background: url(../images/filter-icn.png) no-repeat center right !important;
padding: 0px !important;
cursor: pointer;
float: right;
vertical-align: middle;
margin: 0 0 0 10px !important;
font-size: 12px;
letter-spacing: 0.5px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 99999;
top: 70px;
right: 15px;
outline: 0 !important;
}
```

Here is my html

```
<form id="search_form">     
<input type="button" class="filterIcon" id="iconfilter">
</form>
```

Comment: share your  code!!!!!

Comment: Can you add code or post it in plunker/fiddle?

Comment: Why don't you try this in a browser debugger, by examining the element's CSS? You can find out if it has any property which is setting the outline huh?

Comment: And which browser do you use?

Comment: @לבנימלכה added code

Comment: I try to run it in and I see no dots on click.... maybe attach jsFiddle or somthing

Comment: @RomeoSierra the thing is that if i click anywhere on the screen it disappears, even on the console.

Comment: Well.. to me it looks like the button is being highlighted when you click on it. When you press **TAB** key when you see it, what happens?

Comment: @RomeoSierra when I press tab it disappears

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anchor links ('s) by default have a dotted outline around them when they become "active" or "focused".

If you want it gone, and you want it gone on every single anchor link, just include this as a part of your CSS reset:

```
a, button {
  outline: 0;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
  /* styling for any way a link is about to be used */
}
```

Firefox Inputs Clicking down on an input type=image can produce a dotted outline
To remove it: `input::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; }`

Source : https://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/

Comment: Ok. Thanks. `input::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; }` This fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to determine without any additional info but try adding this to the button’s css

```
outline: 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but outline doesn't seem to fix it. I have added my code for further reference. Would appreciate if u look at it once.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox 59.04 64 bit on ubuntu 17.10. I checked and chrome doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Its because of outline, you can try this code.

```
button, button:hover, button:focus, button:active,
a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The dotted border is there for accessibility reasons as a visual clue of what has been selected (clicked on). You can get rid of this easily by adding this CSS to the elements (class name depends on the element):

```
.button {
  outline: none;
}
```

`outline` on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline):

> The outline CSS property is a shorthand for setting various outline properties in a single declaration: outline-style, outline-width, and outline-color.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the outline with this code:

```
outline: none;
```